# How do I print values from mongodb in my javascript code?

Tags: javascript, python, mongodb, bottle

I'm trying to take values from my Mongo collection and print them out on my webpage which.  I'm using javascript and I'm also using the bottle framework and python to communicate database queries between the webpage and the database.  Any suggestions as to what I should do?

Comment: You could read manuals and quick-starts on your selected technologies. Normally, basic questions are covered there.

Comment: Are you using Javascript server-sided or client-sided?

Comment: This is going to sound really stupid but I don't know.  I've got my mongodb running on my computer (localhost, I'm think this would be client side).  I'm running everything on my computer, that should make it client side correct?

Comment: Maybe you should first learn the basics of web development before you start complicating it by using databases.

Answer (score 0):

Try to look into Mongoose, I use it to fetch data from MongoDB in my node.js application.

Answer (score 0):

Bottle is a python web framework, you should use pymongo (the official mongodb python driver) to query and return results.

You can get a tutorial on pymongo here: http://api.mongodb.org/python/current/tutorial.html

Comment: I am using pymongo to query the database, but I want to display my result on my webpage.  Again I'm using bottle as my framework

Comment: I'm not sure what you are asking. You have a database (mongo) and a web framework (bottle). You query the database using pymongo within the web framework when a request comes in and return the response to the client (browser).